# Centralizing OutputCache values in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, caching

We're starting to apply output caching to many of our pages as we start load testing our app.  I'm wondering if there is a way to centralize the values we are using, say in the web.config, as we have many pages on which we'll be experimenting with different values.

In general, I just like the idea of being able to change the values in one location... does anyone know if this is possible?

Something like <%@ OutputCache Duration="ValueFromWebConfig" VaryByParam="none" %>

I'm guessing maybe not as the value needs to be a compile time constant, but I just wanted to check with you gurus before I gave up :)

Thanks a bunch.

Evan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, using profiles. Straight from MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228270.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jaimal, that's just what I was looking for.